# Other Virtualization/Infrustructure Software Similar to VMware vSphere

Tags: untagged

Does it exist? Something that can (HOST) and manage multiple virtual machines, backup, migration from physical to virtual etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are commercial products like RHEV or Xenserver, and open solutions like oVirt, Convirt, Proxmox and others

Comment: mainframes? really? can I see a prooflink please? RHEV can scale to hundreds of hosts per single migration domain, running thousands of VMs, but this has nothing to do with MF

Comment: Who said anything about mainframes?

Comment: he (or she) deleted all the comments to avoid embarrassment I suppose

Comment: Thanks @dyasny . Highly interested in the open source solutions. Paying $10,000 for a single license to scale 4+ servers is a little pricey =/

Comment: I'm no sales person, but the pricing of RHEV is quite reasonable, especially since you're never left alone in the fight if anything goes wrong. If you prefer to boldly go where nobody will support you, there's oVirt.org, which definitely deserves a look

Answer (score 0):

I think Microsoft might even have some products in this space....

I know that this type of answer isn't encouraged on this site, but I suggest you take a spin around the ol' Wikipedia next time *first* before asking a question like this.

Comment: i suppose so  =P